# array output showing up as null

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package freewill_project;

import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ///
 */
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int batas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Batas Siswa"));
        String[] nama = new String[batas];
        String mapel1, mapel2;
        int nilai1[] = new int[batas];
        int nilai2[] = new int[batas];
        int total1 = 0, total2 = 0, Ttotal;
        int kkm1, kkm2, k=0;

        String[] tlulus1 = new String[nama.length];
        String[] lulus1 = new String[nama.length];
        String[] tlulus2 = new String[nama.length];
        String[] lulus2 = new String[nama.length];
        int jumlah = 0;
        mapel1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Masukan Mapel 1");
        mapel2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Masukan Mapel 2");
        kkm1 = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input KKM 1")));
        kkm2 = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input KKM 2")));

        for (int i = 0; i < nama.length; i++) {
            nama[i] = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nama Siswa"));
            nilai1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Nilai"));
            total1 += nilai1[i];
            if (nilai1[i] < kkm1) {
                tlulus1[i] = nama[i];
            } else {
                nama[i] = lulus1[i];
            }
            nilai2[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Nilai"));
            total2 += nilai2[i];
            if (nilai2[i] < kkm2) {
                nama[i] = tlulus2[i];
            } else {
                nama[i] = lulus2[i];
            }
        }


        Ttotal = total1 + total2;
        int rata = Ttotal / 2;
        int max1 = nilai1[0];
        int min1 = nilai1[0];
        int max2 = nilai2[0];
        int min2 = nilai2[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //for untuk output max, min, jumlah, rata arrays
            if (max1 < nilai1[i]) {
                max1 = nilai1[i];
            } else if (min1 > nilai1[i]) {
                min1 = nilai1[i];
            }
            if (max2 < nilai2[i]) {
                max2 = nilai2[i];
            } else if (min2 > nilai2[i]) {
                min2 = nilai2[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Nilai Rata: " + rata + "\nNilai Tertinggi1: " + max1 + "\nNilai Terendah1: " + min2 + "\nNilai Tertinggi2: " + max2 + "\nNilai Terendah2: " + min2 + "\nSiswa Lulus1: " + Arrays.toString(lulus1) + "\nSiswa Tidak Lulus1: " + Arrays.toString(tlulus1) + "\nSiswa Lulus2: " + Arrays.toString(lulus2) + "\nSiswa Tidak Lulus2: " + Arrays.toString(tlulus2));
    }
}
```

if the nilai is less than the kkm, then an element of the array in nama will be copied to tlulus, else an element in nama will be copied to lulus, however the output shows both lulus and tlulus as null

the output of lulus and tlulus should contain elements of nama, it showed up as null instead, I tried several fixes but then I get Arrays.outofbounds exception, any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When asking a question, please post the code in an understandable format. Your variable naming is not helpful at all. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```java
} else {
    nama[i] = lulus1[i];
}
```

does not seem to match your specification:

> *else an element in nama will be copied to lulus*

Shouldn't it rather be

```java
} else {
    lulus1[i] = nama[i];
}
```

?

Your code can lead to `nama` inputs being overwritten with `null`.